# Arbitrum gas fees calculation

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, brotli

we are trying to calculate the expected gas limit that we would encounter on Arbitrum for transactions. Not any cross-chain messages, specifically just transactions on L2.

We are relying on the formula from this [article](https://developer.arbitrum.io/devs-how-tos/how-to-estimate-gas).
To summarise the formula:
`Gas Limit (G) = Gas used on L2 (L2G) + Extra Buffer for L1 cost (B)`

I'm using this [transaction](https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x44bd494620135e0e02afb656e40b40d6fff962cc5819d96142088a3dbd3a9c74) as an testing example. I'm taking data from there, like `L2G`. Forked the chain on Tenderly to interact with the values that were in the previous block.

Currently the only thing I'm suspicious of is the txData size. Since it might has to be fetched differently. I brotli compressed it and took the byte length. All other values are pretty straightforward and coming from ARB contract directly.

Yes, we know we can use the `eth_estimateGas` option. But that is the **last** resort for us. We would like to avoid that one, and have some estimates in advance. We don't have to be wei precise, but don't want to miss the calculation by 10m.

Here is a Go playground example https://play.golang.com/p/Gku1ROZzk2N

*Same code here just for reference:*

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Running test")
    estimatedL2GasUsed := uint64(808_704)
    estimatedPricePerByte := uint64(2082873591392)
    dataSize := uint64(3265 + 140)
    arbGasPrice := uint64(100000000)

    fmt.Println(calculate(
        estimatedL2GasUsed,
        estimatedPricePerByte,
        dataSize,
        arbGasPrice,
    ))
}

func calculate(estimatedL2GasUsed uint64, estimatedPricePerByte uint64, l1DataSize uint64, arbGasPrice uint64) uint64 {
    return estimatedL2GasUsed + ((estimatedPricePerByte * l1DataSize) / arbGasPrice)
}
```

I would expect the result to be around 20m as it is on Arbiscan, but the result ends up being around 70m.

Relying on a Tenderly fork on block: 98092196

But also when using a live RPC the results don't add up.